# There is an equivalent to isPointInFill for Firefox?"

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

I created a few charts on D3.js and they are running well at Chrome. However I'm having the follow error on Firefox.

`Error: path.isPointInFill is not a function`

I have looked at the documentation, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill, and it's not supported on Firefox, but I didn't found an equivalent or a substitute.

**What I need to do:**
I have a chart XY, which is separated into several paths (with different shapes). I'm plotting the results from an user in X and Y and I need that the path where the users is located change the color.

Follow example..

[image]

...after that I plotted the user I need change the color of the p6.

Comment: You note each path has a different shape, but the image shows a regular grid. I've got a couple questions that could help clarify: are there overlapping paths, and are the paths gridded in some way?

Comment: Try a [Firefox nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/) support for isPointInFill just landed.

Comment: Andrew, I used the regular grid to simplify and because I can't share the actual chart.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, that works well... but I still need a solution to the others versions of Firefox. Do you think it would be possible to change the function or another way I can solve that?

Comment: What about [document.elementFromPoint](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-document-elementfrompoint)?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried but seems that doesn't work